# Wrong intercept, but remaining betas are right. Where is the error?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, econometrics

I'm trying to learn how to use R by replicating the regression of the [MRW 1992](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2118477) paper (see Table 1). I've done this in Mathematica, and I got the right coefficients, even for the intercept.

The following R script is what I'm using for this example:

```
library(foreign)
mrw <- read.dta("https://www.nuffield.ox.ac.uk/teaching/economics/bond/mrw.dta")

mrw$popgrowth <- mrw$popgrowth/100 #the data is in percentage points
mrw$gdpgrowth <- mrw$gdpgrowth/100 #the data is in percentage points

noil <- mrw[mrw$n==1,] #non-oil countries

form1noil <- log(rgdpw85) ~ 1+log(i_y)+log(popgrowth+0.05) #we have to add 0.05 (see paper)
noil.lm <- lm(form1noil, data = noil)
summary(noil.lm) #the intercept has the wrong value !
#Call:
#lm(formula = form1noil, data = noil)
#
#Residuals:
#     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
#-1.79144 -0.39367  0.04124  0.43368  1.58046 
#
#Coefficients:
#                      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#(Intercept)            -1.1279     1.4274  -0.790 0.431371    
#log(i_y)                1.4240     0.1431   9.951  < 2e-16 ***
#log(popgrowth + 0.05)  -1.9898     0.5634  -3.532 0.000639 ***
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
#Residual standard error: 0.6891 on 95 degrees of freedom
#Multiple R-squared:  0.6009,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.5925 
#F-statistic: 71.51 on 2 and 95 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

The strange thing is that I get the wrong intercept, but all the remaining betas are correct, and so are the R^2 and the std errors. Why is that?

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:  Mathematica Code and output (data is imported from an excel file, with same values. sav is the i_y column)

```
YL85 = data[[1, 2 ;; n, 3]];
sav = data[[1, 2 ;; n, 6]]/100;
popgr = data[[1, 2 ;; n, 5]]/100;

logYL85 = Log[YL85];
logsav = Log[sav];
logrates = Log[popgr + 0.05];

lm = LinearModelFit[
   Transpose[{logsav, logrates, logYL85}], {x1, x2}, {x1, x2}];

Normal[lm]

5.42988 + 1.42401 x1 - 1.98977 x2
```

Comment: I think the model syntax is wrong - should have lm(y~x) and not lm(y,x)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Not sure I understand what you've written. The command works in this way lm(formula, data.frame). I've never seen '~' inside the command...

Comment: The comment/answer is incorrect: `f <- mpg ~ cyl; lm(f, mtcars)` works properly since `f` is a formula-object.

Comment: the model syntax is correct

Comment: I have no explanation. Results should be equal. Can you check whether the data is exactly the same in R and in Mathematica?

Comment: Since we have no way to determine what the "right" intercept is--we would be trusting the `R` results--and because obviously you are using a different representation of the data in *Mathematica*, there does not appear to be any way to diagnose or answer this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that in the Mathematica case, you are rescaling the `i_y` (i.e. `sav`) variable by a factor of 100, but this is not done in the R case; instead the `gdpgrowth` variable is rescaled, but this variable is not used in the model. Since the logarithm is being taken of the data, a rescaling would result in the addition of a constant. The discrepancy between the intercept estimates $5.42988-(-1.1279)=6.55778$ is equal to $\log(100)\hat\beta_1 = \log(100)*1.424$, which is exactly what we would expect from this mistake.

Answer (score -2):

If you have clear ideas about the interpretations of multiple correlation coefficients. $\beta_0$ is nothing but the value of response variable when all regressors are at zero level. Hence if it comes out to be insignificant there is nothing wrong in the model as long as adjusted $R^2$ is high,that is your model explains the data. In your case it seem satisfacory enough to me.

Comment: The OP asked why he got two different intercepts, not why either did not reach some arbitrary level of significance.